# Question about the collection of the prime factors of a fibonacci number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, prime-factorization, conjectures, decimal-expansion

A positive integer $n$ is called pandigital , if every digit from $0$ to $9$ occurs in the decimal expansion of $n$.

Conjecture : The largest non-pandigital fibonacci-number (a fibonacci-number with at least one digit missing in the decimal expansion) is $F_{285}$. This is true upto $F_{10^4}$.

> Can this conjecture be proven ?

But I am mainly interested in another construction : We collect the prime factors of the fibonacci-number $F_n$ and look whether the concattenation of those leads to a pandigit-number (in other words , every digit from $0$ to $9$ occurs in at least one of the prime factors). Let us call such a fibonacci-number good , otherwise bad.

> What is the largest bad fibonacci-number ? I guess that the number of bad fibonacci-numbers is finite since the concattenation of the prime factors will in almost all cases be not significantly smaller than the number of digits of $F_n$ itself.

No prime factor of [$F_{312}$](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=I%28312%29) has digit $6$. Upto $F_{380}$ this is the largest such fibonacci-number. Hence the largest "bad" fibonacci-number might be $F_{312}$.

Comment: These are really two separate questions. For the first: Considering the fact that the Fibonacci numbers are periodic mod $10^n$, one might suspect that it suffices to simply compute all Fibonacci remainders mod $10^n$ for some moderate value of $n$, say $n=20$.

Comment: @Servaes That doesn’t seem very likely to work, even if it were practical… if I sample even $10^{10}$ numbers with $20$ digits each, it’s quite likely that *some* of them won’t be pandigital, no?  And that’s still true for larger $n$, with the additional problem that we can’t check them all in a reasonable time.

Comment: I'm pessimistic with finding a prove for the first conjecture. The analogue problem for powers of $2$ in base $10$ or $3$ should have received more attention but no answer yet.